# Did touch function not working in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

```
import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene {
    var cam: SKCameraNode?
    var player: SKSpriteNode?
    
    
    
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
       super.didMove(to: view)
       cam = SKCameraNode()
       self.camera = cam
       self.addChild(cam!)
        player = self.childNode(withName: "player") as? SKSpriteNode
    }
    
     func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let touch:UITouch = touches.anyObject() as! UITouch
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

        if touchLocation.x < self.frame.size.width / 2 {
            let moveRight = SKAction.moveBy(x: 300, y: 0, duration: 1)
            player?.run(moveRight)
        } else {
            let moveLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: -300, y: 0, duration: 1)
            player?.run(moveLeft)
            
        }
    }
    
    
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        super.update(currentTime)
        if let camera = cam, let pl = player {
          camera.position = pl.position
        }
      }
    
    
}
```

That is my whole game scene and the sprites I have dragged and dropped onto the screen using the sk scene. I have added a camera to the scene if that affects anything. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you should be overriding the touchesBegan function not creating your own one.

Comment: @JohnL gives me this error - Method does not override any method from its superclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the touches began function. It also helps to put in a print statement to show that touches are being received.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  for touch in touches {
  print("touch detected")
  let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

   if touchLocation.x < self.frame.size.width / 2 {
       let moveRight = SKAction.moveBy(x: 300, y: 0, duration: 1)
       player?.run(moveRight)
   } else {
       let moveLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: -300, y: 0, duration: 1)
       player?.run(moveLeft)
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you it works but only seems to move right no matter where I tap it. I think its because I specified the frame size rather than the actual view being shown. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: I'd suggest you print touchLocation.x and touch the screen multiple times to get an idea of the data you are dealing with. Print out frame.size.width also. Compare the 2 as they form the 2 parts of your if statement.

Comment: You can look into player?.removeAllActions() before running the moveRight or moveLeft action, it will stop any actions currently running on the node.

Comment: So when I touch the extreme right it goes left and then when I tap it again in the same place it goes right again lol. I will do as you instructed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene {
    var cam: SKCameraNode?
    var player: SKSpriteNode?
    
    
    
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
       super.didMove(to: view)
       cam = SKCameraNode()
       self.camera = cam
       self.addChild(cam!)
        player = self.childNode(withName: "player") as? SKSpriteNode
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      for touch in touches {
      print("touch detected")
      let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

        if touchLocation.x < (player?.position.x)! {
           let moveRight = SKAction.moveBy(x: 300, y: 0, duration: 1)
        print("right")
           player?.run(moveRight)
       } else {
           let moveLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: -300, y: 0, duration: 1)
        print("Left")
           player?.run(moveLeft)
       }
      }
     }
    
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        super.update(currentTime)
        if let camera = cam, let pl = player {
          camera.position = pl.position
        }
      }
    
    
}
```

I figured it out with the help of JohnL. By adding if touchLocation.x < (player?.position.x)! instead of if touchLocation.x < self.frame.size.width / 2